# getting error as unhandaled promise rejection waning

Tags: javascript, node.js, es6-promise

I have to save some data in my db on the basis of some calls so I ma using promises for that but getting error as `unhandled promise rejection` I don't know what is going wrong.

I have a controller where first of all I am checking something by running a query then if rows exists then next I am checking count if count is 0 execution one function else want to handle other function.

My controller

```
exports.dispenceCashback = function(req, res) {
    const phoneNo = req.body.phoneNo
    const billAmt = req.body.billAmt
    const cashBack = req.body.cashBack
    const billNo = req.body.billNo
    User.isValidConsumer(phoneNo)
        .then(([rows]) => {

        if (rows[0]) {   // if consumer valid / exist then go forward
            console.log(rows)
            let consumerName = rows[0].consumername

            User.checkRows(phoneNo)
                .then(([rows]) => {

                console.log(rows[0].count)
                if (rows[0].count == 0) {  // checking what is the count of row if 0 then executing this code
                    User.insertIntoDets(phoneNo, billAmt, cashBack, billNo, consumerName, retailerName, retailerId)
                    User.insertNew(phoneNo, billAmt, cashBack, consumerName)

                    } 
                    else {    //else do this functanility
                         User.insertIntoDets(phoneNo, billAmt, cashBack, billNo, consumerName, retailerName, retailerId)
                         User.update(phoneNo, billAmt, cashBack)
                    }
                })
                .catch(error => {
                    console.log(error)
                    return res.status(404).json({ error: 'Something went wrong' })
                })

            } 
            else {
                return res.status(404).json({ error: 'Ooooops!!!! invalid consumer' })
            }
        })
        .catch(err => console.log(err));
    }
```

And with respect to above code here is my model class where I am running my queries

```
static isValidConsumer(phoneNo) {
    let sql = 'select *  from tpconsumer where consphoneno = ?'
    return db.execute(sql, [phoneNo]);
}

static checkRows(phoneNo) {
    let sql = 'select count(*) as count from cashbackdisp where consphoneno = ?'
    return db.execute(sql, [phoneNo]);
}

static insertIntoDets(phoneNo, billAmt, cashBack, billNo, consumerName, retailerName, retailerId) {

    console.log(retailerId, retailerName)
    let today = new Date();
    let dd = String(today.getDate()).padStart(2, '0');
    let mm = String(today.getMonth() + 1).padStart(2, '0');
    let yyyy = today.getFullYear();
    today = yyyy + '-' + mm + '-' + dd;

    let sql = 'INSERT INTO cashbackdispdets (consphoneno, consumername, businessid, businessname, billamt, cashbackamt, billno, billdate, billyear)VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?,?)'
    return db.execute(sql, [phoneNo, consumerName, retailerId, retailerName, billAmt, cashBack, billNo, today, yyyy, 'Y']);
}

static insertNew(phoneNo, billAmt, cashBack, consumerName) {
    let sql = 'INSERT INTO cashbackdisp (consphoneno, consumername, curyearpurchasedamt, curyearcashbackamt) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)'
    return db.execute(sql, [phoneNo, consumerName, billAmt, cashBack]);
}

static update(phoneNo, billAmt, cashBack) {
    let sql = 'UPDATE cashbackdisp SET  curyearpurchasedamt = curyearpurchasedamt+ ' + billAmt + ',curyearcashbackamt = curyearcashbackamt + ' + cashBack + ' WHERE consphoneno = ?'
    console.log("sql  :" + sql)
    return db.execute(sql, [phoneNo]);

}
```

I have commented some lines in my controller where I am doing things error I am getting is :

> [image: this]

Comment: `Column count doesn't match value count`.

Comment: you have an error in `insertIntoDebts`, this function returns a promise, you  haven't got a `.catch` on that promise, therefore you have an `unhandled promise rejection` - all of that is clearly spelled out in the error message

Comment: Neither of the times you use `User.insertIntoDets`, `User.insertNew` and `User.update` you are catching them in case they fail. 
Besides that `insertIntoDets` you are using 10 query params inside and insertion of 9 fields.

Comment: @JaromandaX  you are saying that I have to catch in all methods like `User.insertIntoDets(phoneNo, billAmt, cashBack, billNo, consumerName, retailerName, retailerId).then(() =>{console.log("saved").catch(err=>{console.log(err) })`

Comment: well, that won't fix the underlying error, but it will stop the `unhandled rejection warning`

Comment: @Dez for each of them I have to put .then and .catch correct

Comment: yes, but that won't fix the error in your code - you will still get an error

Comment: @JaromandaX  column count is not matching it says but the count is correct :(

Comment: not according to another comment

Comment: `consphoneno, consumername, businessid, businessname, billamt, cashbackamt, billno, billdate, billyear` 9 fields .... `?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?,?` 10 question marks ... ... now, I'm not a Mathematics professor, so I can't **prove** beyond doubt that 9 !== 10 ... but I'm fairly certain that is the case

Comment: @JaromandaX ohhhh I didn't saw that so sorry for that, I wasted my full time on this :(, thanx

Comment: Dez mentioned it 28 minutes ago :D